# Gradient not drawing

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Im trying to draw gradients in android

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 20;
        int gh = this.height /4 ;
        int gw = this.width;
        Paint paint  = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(10);
        for(Todo t : todos){

            canvas.drawText(t.title, x, y, paint);
            grad.setBounds(x, y, gw, gh);
            grad.draw(canvas);
            y+= gh;
        }
        this.invalidate();
    }
```

and the gradient

```
    GradientDrawable  grad = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
        new int[]{0xffffffff, 0xffff00ff});
```

the todo title draws,but theres no gradient. when i just drew the gradient at 0,0 it worked fine

Comment: Have you considered placing the drawing instructions in an XML file in a drawable folder, I find that's easier to work with.

Comment: Arnt xmls static though? the user of my app can add/remove todos

Comment: Yes they are, but you can define multiple drawables if you want.  Also, from the above code, its unclear when you intend to draw these gradients; i.e. once, or whenever there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

are you shure that grad is not drawn? you draw it in loop so you can see only a small part of it. is it resizing? or you just draw a part of it?

Comment: grad.setBounds(x, y, gw, gh); i set the size of the grad to the width of the screen,and the hieght /4

Comment: are bounds relative?
maybe you must write grad.setBounds(x, y, x + gw, y + gh);
sorry, can't check it myself